# How to upload image using ajax and zend?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

Thank you for the consideration, I'm sorry for my non-informative question.

Actually I am using ajax and zend for uploading a file.

My ajax code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/business_general/imagesave",
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       data: {'file': files.getAsBinary(), 'fname' : file.fileName},
       success: function(arrReturn){
          alert( "Data Uploaded: ");
       }
});
```

Here, I called a controller action(imagesave) to save my image in database

My Controller file action looks like this:

```
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    $vehiclelogo = $config->paths->vehiclelogo;
    $file = $objRequest->getParam('file');
    $ret = $objRequest->getParam('fname');
    $path_parts = pathinfo($ret);

    echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
    echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";

    $targetPath = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

    try {
        echo "POSTED FILE NAME"." ". $ret;
        echo "TYPE OF FILE UPLOADED"." "."-". gettype($ret);
        $strFilePath = $vehiclelogo.'/'.$targetPath.'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
        $OPfile = fopen($strFilePath,"w"); 
        fwrite($OPfile,$file);
        fclose($OPfile);
        echo "completed";
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "error";
    }
```

Here, I am uploading the selected image into a folder.Acually, I am able to upload text files. But if I upload png/jpeg files,it gets uploaded into the folder, But the fact is that it could not be opened.

I should be able to able to upload every type of files.

How to execute this in zend-php and ajax?

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code and take a look if you can't improve the wording of your question here or there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry .I think getAsBinary() doesn't support in modern browsers.you can use an invisible canvas for uploding files using ajax.

Example

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      var strdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      document.getElementById("company_logo").src=strdata;
        $.ajax({
   type: "POST",                                                  
     url: "/business_vehicle/vehiclegeneralsave",                     
    data: "&data="+strdata,
    success: function(arrResult) {
```

//do something

```
    }
});
```

In controller side you can recive the image ` public function vehiclegeneralsaveAction() {

```
    $file    =  $arrVehicleDetails = trim($objRequest->getParam('data'));

      $strEncodedData = str_replace(' ', '+', $file);
    $strFilteredData = explode(',', $strEncodedData);
    $strUnencoded = base64_decode($strFilteredData[1]);

    file_put_contents('../public/image/image.png', $strUnencoded);
   }`
```